# Updates and Creations Not Reflecting in GET Requests in Strapi

Tags: strapi

I'm encountering an issue in my Strapi application where updates and creations made within the Strapi UI are not immediately reflected in GET requests.

- When I create or update data directly within the Strapi administrative interface, the changes are not consistently reflected when retrieving the same data via GET requests.
- Despite confirming that the data has been successfully created or updated within the Strapi UI, there is a delay in reflecting these changes in GET responses.

I assume it might be caching issue.

Strapi version: v4.11.4

I'm seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue to ensure that updates and creations are consistently reflected in GET responses when using the Strapi administrative interface.
Any insights or assistance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

In Strapi administrative interface when I click on purge REST cache multiple times then the changes are getting reflected.